# CTest can not find tests in simple test setup

Tags: c++, cmake, ctest

I am adding unit tests to my library but ctest always says `No tests were found!!!`.

In my top level `CMakeLists.txt` I have the following

```
option(BUILD_TESTS OFF)

if (${BUILD_TESTS})
  enable_testing()
  add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

and int `test/CMakeLists.txt`

```
enable_testing()

project(test CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})

add_test(my_test ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_sources(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE
    test.cpp
)
```

My `test.cpp` just has a simple `main()`

```
bool test() {
  return true;
}

int main(int, char**) {
  return test() ? 0 : 1;
}
```

When I build with `cmake --build build/` it even generates a `CTestTestfile.cmake` file in the build directory.
But when I now run `ctest -C Debug` I get the `No tests were found!!!` message.

How can I get this basic test to work?

Comment: Uh, are your tests just off? `option(BUILD_TESTS OFF)` would suggest as much.

Comment: @Dr.Watson I used -DBUILD_TESTS=True when I generated the project. As I said the test files are even generated

Comment: Did you build them?